# How do I detect if a QImage is animated?

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qtgui

I'm using Qt 5.2 and I have a QImage. If it detects an image url (such as an imgur link) it downloads that image and displays it. I want to also animate it if the image is animated (such as a gif).

I tried going by extension, but some links will end in jpg and still be animated. I'm currently using [`QImage::format()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#format) to check for `Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied` but I've come across some animated images that come back as `Format_RGB32` or `Format_ARGB32` which is the same format as static images.

Is there a better way that I can check that header info to get more consistent results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use QImageReader to read the image, and [QImageReader::supportsAnimation()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportsAnimation) and [QImageReader::imageCount()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimagereader.html#imageCount) to check if it's an animated image. Once you have only a QImage, that information will be lost, as QImage represents only one frame, i.e. a static image.

To display animated images, use [QMovie](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmovie.html). In QtQuick, the element [AnimatedImage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html) displays animated images.

Comment: I was reluctant to try this at first because it looked like it required a file on the disk, and I wanted to do it from memory. Upon further investigation it looks like QBuffer inherits QIODevice which would work perfectly.